# Libgdx 3d issue with zero coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx

game in 3d (all float numbers)
player movement:

```
public void update(float dt){ //in MainClass dt = Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1/20f);

    this.dt = dt;
    time += 60*dt;

    collision = new NigelCollision(getPos(), dir, kick);
controller.update(dt);
    detector.detectCollisions(4, 0, 1, getPos(), dir, speed *dt, vspeed, dt);

    if (detector.isDetect()) {
        if (kick){
            sword2.play();
            bSword2.opacity = 0;
            bSword1.opacity = 1;
            bSwing.opacity = 0;
            if (detector.isBottomDetect())
                controller.setAnimation("stay");
            else controller.setAnimation("jump-D");
            kick = false;
        }
        if (!gShifted) {
            speed = detector.getGshift();
            gShifted = true;
        }
        else speed = 0;
    }
    else gShifted = false;

    if (detector.isBottomDetect() || onPlatform) {
        if(fall == true){
            if (speed > 0)
            controller.setAnimation("move", -1);
            else controller.setAnimation("stay");
            jump2.play();
            fall = false;
        }
        if (!vShifted) {
            vspeed = -detector.getVshift();
            vShifted = true;
        }
        else vspeed = 0;
    }
    else {
        if(fall == false && vspeed < 0){
            controller.setAnimation("jump-D");
            fall = true;
        }
        if (!climb) {
            vShifted = false;
            gravity = 1.2f * dt;
        }
        if(vspeed > -36 *dt)
            vspeed-= gravity;
    }

    if (climb && !detector.isRopeDetect()) {
        if(!vShifted) {
            vspeed = detector.getVshift();
            vShifted = true;
        }
        else {
            move(dir);
            vspeed = 0;
            climbing.stop();
            climb = false;
            vShifted = false;
        }
    }
    if (detector.isRopeDetect()) {
        if (!climb) {
            climb();
            gravity = 0;
            climb = true;
        }
    }
    //else climb = false;
    if (detector.isPlatformDetect()) onPlatform = true;
    if (detector.isBottomDetect()) onPlatform = false;
    if (onPlatform) {
        if (dir == 0)
            nigel.transform.translate(detector.getpSpeed().x, detector.getpSpeed().y,
                    detector.isDetect() || onPos ? speed + detector.getpSpeed().z: speed *dt + detector.getpSpeed().z);
        if (dir == 90)
            nigel.transform.translate(-detector.getpSpeed().z, vspeed + detector.getpSpeed().y,
                    detector.isDetect() || onPos ? speed + detector.getpSpeed().x: speed *dt + detector.getpSpeed().x);
        if (dir == 180)
            nigel.transform.translate(-detector.getpSpeed().x, vspeed + detector.getpSpeed().y,
                    detector.isDetect() || onPos ? speed - detector.getpSpeed().z: speed *dt - detector.getpSpeed().z);
        if (dir == 270)
            nigel.transform.translate(detector.getpSpeed().z, vspeed + detector.getpSpeed().y,
                    detector.isDetect() || onPos ? speed - detector.getpSpeed().x: speed *dt - detector.getpSpeed().x);
    }
    else nigel.transform.translate(0, detector.isRopeDetect()? vspeed *dt: vspeed,
                detector.isDetect() || onPos? speed: speed *dt);
```

other methods of player:

```
public void kick(int rot){

    //k = 0;
    controller.setAnimation("kick", 1, 0.7f, new AnimationController.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnd(AnimationController.AnimationDesc animation) {

            controller.setAnimation("stay", -1);
            bSword2.opacity = 0;
            bSword1.opacity = 1;
            bSwing.opacity = 0;
            kick = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoop(AnimationController.AnimationDesc animation) {

        }
    });
    bSword2.opacity = 1;
    bSword1.opacity = 0;
    sword1.play();
    bSwing.opacity = 0.5f;
    kick = true;
}

public void movedKick(int rot){

    //k = 0;
    controller.setAnimation("kick", 1, 0.7f, new AnimationController.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnd(AnimationController.AnimationDesc animation) {

            controller.setAnimation("move", -1);
            bSword2.opacity = 0;
            bSword1.opacity = 1;
            bSwing.opacity = 0;
            kick = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoop(AnimationController.AnimationDesc animation) {

        }
    });
    speed = 12;
    bSword2.opacity = 1;
    bSword1.opacity = 0;
    sword1.play();
    bSwing.opacity = 0.5f;
    kick = true;
}

public void move(int rot){

    speed = 12;
    nigel.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y, rot - dir);
    if (detector.isBottomDetect() || onPlatform)
        controller.setAnimation("move", -1);
    dir = rot;
}

public void stay(int rot){

    speed = 0;
    nigel.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y, rot - dir);
    if (detector.isBottomDetect() || onPlatform)
    controller.setAnimation("stay");
    dir = rot;
}

public void jump(int rot){

    if (detector.isBottomDetect() || onPlatform) {
        onPlatform = false;
        vspeed = 0.4f;
        if(!kick)
            controller.setAnimation("jump-U");
        jump1.play();

        bSword2.opacity = 0;
        bSword1.opacity = 1;
        bSwing.opacity = 0;
    }
}

public void take(){

}

public void climb(){

    vspeed = 5;
    controller.setAnimation("move-U", -1);
    climbing.play();
    climbing.loop();
}

public void damage(){

}

public void die(){

}

public void setPos(){

    nigel.transform.setTranslation(newPos);
}

public Vector3 getPos() {

    return nigel.transform.getTranslation(pos);
}
```

collision detector:

```
public void detectCollisions(int height, int centerY, int radius, Vector3 position, int dir, float speed, float vspeed, float dt){

    frontDetectX = frontDetectZ = backDetectX = backDetectZ = bottomDetect = topDetect = ropeDetect = platformDetect = kickDetect = false;

    nigelCollision = nigel.collision;
    if(nigelCollision.kick && position != nigelCollision.pos)
        if(position.y - nigelCollision.pos.y < 3 && nigelCollision.pos.y - position.y < 3) {
            if (nigelCollision.rot == 0 && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z < 4 && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z >= 1
                    && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x <= 2 && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x >= -2)
                kickDetect = true;
            if (nigelCollision.rot == 270 && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x > -4 && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x <= -1
                    && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z <= 2 && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z >= -2)
                kickDetect = true;
            if (nigelCollision.rot == 180 && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z > -4 && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z <= -1
                    && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x <= 2 && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x >= -2)
                kickDetect = true;
            if (nigelCollision.rot == 90 && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x < 4 && position.x - nigelCollision.pos.x >= 1
                    && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z <= 2 && position.z - nigelCollision.pos.z >= -2)
                kickDetect = true;
        }

    for (int p = 0; p < platforms.size; p++){

        if(platforms.get(p).pos.y +1 + platforms.get(p).yspeed >= position.y - centerY + vspeed - 1.2f *dt
                && platforms.get(p).pos.y +1 + platforms.get(p).yspeed < position.y - centerY + height
                && platforms.get(p).pos.z > position.z -2 && platforms.get(p).pos.z < position.z +2
                && platforms.get(p).pos.x > position.x -2 && platforms.get(p).pos.x < position.x +2) {
            platformDetect = true;
            //bottomDetect = true;
            vshift = position.y - centerY - (platforms.get(p).pos.y + 1 + platforms.get(p).yspeed);
            pNum = p;
        }
        pSpeed = new Vector3(platforms.get(pNum).xspeed, platforms.get(pNum).yspeed, platforms.get(pNum).zspeed);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size; i++){

        if(walls.get(i).rot.x == 0)
            if(walls.get(i).endPos.y > position.y - centerY -1 && walls.get(i).beginPos.y < position.y - centerY + height +1){
                if(pSpeed.x < 0 && position.x - radius + pSpeed.x <= walls.get(i).endPos.x +1 && position.x - radius >= walls.get(i).endPos.x +1
                        && position.z > walls.get(i).beginPos.z -1 - radius && position.z < walls.get(i).endPos.z +1 + radius) {
                    pSpeed.x = (position.x - radius) - (walls.get(i).endPos.x +1);
                }
                if(pSpeed.x > 0 && position.x + radius + pSpeed.x >= walls.get(i).beginPos.x -1 && position.x + radius <= walls.get(i).beginPos.x -1
                        && position.z > walls.get(i).beginPos.z -1 - radius && position.z < walls.get(i).endPos.z +1 + radius) {
                    pSpeed.x = (walls.get(i).endPos.x -1) - (position.x + radius);
                }
                if(pSpeed.z < 0 && position.z - radius + pSpeed.z <= walls.get(i).endPos.z +1 && position.z - radius >= walls.get(i).endPos.z +1
                        && position.x > walls.get(i).beginPos.x -1 - radius && position.x < walls.get(i).endPos.x +1 + radius) {
                    pSpeed.z = (position.z - radius) - (walls.get(i).endPos.z +1);
                }
                if(pSpeed.z > 0 && position.z + radius + pSpeed.z >= walls.get(i).beginPos.z -1 && position.z + radius <= walls.get(i).beginPos.z -1
                        && position.x > walls.get(i).beginPos.x -1 - radius && position.x < walls.get(i).endPos.x +1 + radius) {
                    pSpeed.z = (walls.get(i).endPos.z -1) - (position.z + radius);
                }
            }

        if(walls.get(i).rot.x == -90)
            if(walls.get(i).endPos.y +1 >= position.y - centerY + vspeed - 1.2f *dt && walls.get(i).endPos.y +1 < position.y - centerY + height                              //?
                    && walls.get(i).endPos.z > position.z -2 && walls.get(i).beginPos.z < position.z +2
                    && walls.get(i).endPos.x > position.x -2 && walls.get(i).beginPos.x < position.x +2) {
                bottomDetect = true;
                vshift = position.y - centerY - (walls.get(i).endPos.y + 1);
            }

        if(speed > 0 && walls.get(i).rot.x == 0){
            if(walls.get(i).endPos.y > position.y - centerY -1 && walls.get(i).beginPos.y < position.y - centerY + height +1){
                if(dir == 90 && walls.get(i).beginPos.x <= position.x + speed +1 + radius && walls.get(i).beginPos.x >= position.x +1 + radius
                        && walls.get(i).endPos.z > position.z -1 - radius && walls.get(i).beginPos.z < position.z +1 + radius) {
                    frontDetectX = true;
                    gshift = walls.get(i).beginPos.x - (position.x + 1 + radius);
                }
                if(dir == 0 && walls.get(i).beginPos.z <= position.z + speed +1 + radius && walls.get(i).beginPos.z >= position.z +1 + radius
                        && walls.get(i).endPos.x > position.x -1 - radius && walls.get(i).beginPos.x < position.x +1 + radius) {
                    frontDetectZ = true;
                    gshift = walls.get(i).beginPos.z - (position.x + 1 + radius);
                }
                if(dir == 270 && position.x <= walls.get(i).endPos.x + speed +1 + radius && position.x -1 - radius >= walls.get(i).endPos.x
                        && position.z > walls.get(i).beginPos.z -1 - radius && position.z < walls.get(i).endPos.z +1 + radius) {
                    backDetectX = true;
                    gshift = position.x - (walls.get(i).endPos.x + 1 + radius);
                }
                if(dir == 180 && position.z <= walls.get(i).endPos.z + speed +1 + radius && position.z -1 - radius >= walls.get(i).endPos.z
                        && position.x > walls.get(i).beginPos.x -1 - radius && position.x < walls.get(i).endPos.x +1 + radius) {
                    backDetectZ = true;
                    gshift = position.z - (walls.get(i).beginPos.z + 1 + radius);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int o = 0; o < objects.size; o++){

        if (objects.get(o).object.equals("rope") || objects.get(o).object.equals("ropeEnd")){

            if ((dir == 270 && objects.get(o).rot == 90) || (dir == 180 && objects.get(o).rot == 0))
                if(objects.get(o).endPos.y > position.y -1 && objects.get(o).beginPos.y < position.y + height +1) {
                    if (dir == 270 && position.x == objects.get(o).beginPos.x + 2 && position.z < objects.get(o).beginPos.z +0.5f
                            && position.z > objects.get(o).beginPos.z -0.5f) {
                        ropeDetect = true;
                        vshift = objects.get(o).endPos.y - (position.y -1);
                    }
                    if (dir == 180 && position.z == objects.get(o).beginPos.z + 2 && position.x < objects.get(o).beginPos.x +0.5f
                            && position.x > objects.get(o).beginPos.x -0.5f) {
                        ropeDetect = true;
                        vshift = objects.get(o).endPos.y - (position.y -1);
                    }
                }
                if(ropeDetect && objects.get(o).object.equals("ropeEnd")){
                    if(objects.get(o).endPos.y +1 < position.y) {
                        vshift = position.y - objects.get(o).endPos.y +1;
                                //objects.get(o).endPos.y - (position.y - 1);
                        ropeDetect = false;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

public boolean isDetect(){

    if(frontDetectX || frontDetectZ || backDetectX || backDetectZ)
        detect = true;
    else detect = false;
    return detect;
}

public boolean isBottomDetect(){

    return bottomDetect;
}

public boolean isRopeDetect(){

    return ropeDetect;
}

public boolean isPlatformDetect(){

    return platformDetect;
}

public boolean isKickDetect(){

    return kickDetect;
}

public  float getVshift(){

    return vshift;
}

public  float getGshift(){

    return gshift;
}

public Vector3 getpSpeed(){

    return pSpeed;
}
```

The player moves along the coordinate x at a speed of 12, the z coordinate is 0
log(speed/position):

```
12.0/(14.0,1.0,0.0) 
12.0/(13.807683,1.0,1.1462985E-8) 
12.0/(13.468298,1.0,3.169194E-8) 
12.0/(13.372773,1.0,3.738564E-8) 
12.0/(13.210449,1.0,4.7060894E-8) 
12.0/(13.011898,1.0,5.889545E-8) 
12.0/(12.803396,1.0,7.132311E-8) 
12.0/(12.609674,1.0,8.2869825E-8) 
12.0/(12.406296,1.0,9.499213E-8) 
12.0/(12.1833935,1.0,1.08278115E-7)
```

the movement along x is correct, z is 0, but the z coordinate changes if the player is drunk!
The problem occurs in zero coordinates, if it goes along the z coordinate, 1 will be correct:

```
12.0/(14.0,1.0,1.0)
12.0/(13.859465,1.0,1.0)
12.0/(13.647637,1.0,1.0)
12.0/(13.364415,1.0,1.0)
12.0/(13.256388,1.0,1.0)
12.0/(13.026965,1.0,1.0)
12.0/(12.545555,1.0,1.0)
```

the same problem occurs when oncoming the zero position
code to move to the desired position(destination position are takes from .json file):

```
public void programmHandling(int id, int pTime, int pos, String method, int value) {

    if(pTime < 0) {
        if(dir == 0 && getPos().z + speed *dt > pos) {
            speed = pos - getPos().z;
            onPos = true;
        }
        if(dir == 90 && getPos().x + speed *dt > pos) {
            speed = pos - getPos().x;
            onPos = true;
        }
        if(dir == 180 && getPos().z - speed *dt < pos){
            speed = getPos().z - pos;
            onPos = true;
        }
        if(dir == 270 && getPos().x - speed *dt < pos){
            speed = getPos().x - pos;
            onPos = true;
        }

        if ((dir == 0 && getPos().z >= pos) || (dir == 180 && getPos().z <= pos) ||
                (dir == 90 && getPos().x >= pos) || (dir == 270 && getPos().x <= pos)) {
            onPos = false;

            try {
                Method m = this.getClass().getMethod(method, int.class);
                m.invoke(this, value);
                if (!method.equals("stay"))
                    speed = 12;
                handler.i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
    else {
        if (time >= pTime) {
            try {
                Method m = this.getClass().getMethod(method, int.class);
                m.invoke(this, value);
                handler.i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

to position 6, the oncoming works correctly

log(speed/position, destination position):

```
12.0/(6.5635056,1.0,1.0),6
12.0/(6.3890247,1.0,1.0),6
0.18205595/(6.182056,1.0,1.0),6
0.0/(6.0,1.0,1.0),6
12.0/(5.6435366,1.0,1.0),0
```

but the oncoming to position 0:

```
12.0/(0.5863363,1.0,1.0),0
12.0/(0.39619145,1.0,1.0),0
0.1771532/(0.1771532,1.0,1.0),0
1.4901161E-8/(1.4901161E-8,1.0,1.0),0
8.881784E-16/(8.881784E-16,1.0,1.0),0
5.293956E-23/(5.293956E-23,1.0,1.0),0
3.1554436E-30/(3.1554436E-30,1.0,1.0),0
1.880791E-37/(1.880791E-37,1.0,1.0),0
1.1E-44/(1.1E-44,1.0,1.0),0
1.1E-44/(0.0,1.0,1.0),0
12.0/(-0.27459404,1.3725406,1.0),-6
```

I do not understand what the problem of searching the Internet did not give anything

Comment: There is not enough info in your question. Post all relevant code that has to do with position and state clearly what you exactly want. Also reduce those logs to just a couple lines, comment if you need to.

Comment: @Madmenyo , i did add more code for information